# Property changes log for Windows Server service

Tags: sharepoint, windows-services, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-security, windows-administration

How can I define who/what made changes on Windows Service property? Are there any log files for such activties?

Problem's birth:

```
- Environment: 
 - OS: Windows Server 2008R2(Front end)
 - App: Sharepoint Foundation 2010.
```

- Problem:

service "Net TCP Listener Adapter" falls down periodically(every day), because dependent service "Net TCP Port Sharing Service" is disabled. I tried to change startup type to "Automatic", everything gone perfect - Net TCP Listener Adapter started successfully. But it was temporary solution, next day start-up type of "Net TCP Port Sharing Service" was turned to disabled. Who made that change? I have only one possible reason: May be, Windows security audit makes changes on that. In event viewer I've noticed that Audit Success executes Filtering Platform Connection at same time, when "Net TCP Listener Adapter" service fallen down. Do you have any idea to define the reason of this problem?